# PowerShell to get all Managed Properties parameters

Tags: 2013, powershell, managed-property, diagnostics

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty -SearchApplication $ssa | fl Name, Type, Description, FullTextQueriable, NoWordBreaker, Queryable, Retrievable, Sortable, RespectPriority, SafeForAnonymous, Weight, ManagedType, FullTextIndex | Out-File D:\test_$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss).txt
```

I am successfully getting back results with this.  The 'Weight' parameter is returning 0 for all managed properties, this is incorrect because my managed property 'Title' has 'Context 1' set in Central Admin, not 'Context 0'.

Here is a sample of the output:

1. Name              : Title;
2. Description       : ;
3. FullTextQueriable : True;
4. NoWordBreaker     : False;
5. Queryable         : True;
6. Retrievable       : True;
7. Sortable          : True;
8. RespectPriority   : True;
9. SafeForAnonymous  : True;
10. Weight           : 0;
11. ManagedType      : Text;
12. FullTextIndex    : ;

How can I correct this or is there a different PowerShell approach to getting back all the information about all managed properties?

I used [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608089.aspx) to help with which parameters to return.